# Change size of backticks in VS Code

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I use Sublime Text, but I'm trying to switch to VS Code.

When I type a backtick (`), in VS Code, they are extremely small, a tremendous irritation to delete them, the automatic closing, but they are so small that I can not see them correctly.

See the backtick on Sublime:

[image]

On VS Code:

[image]

How do I get the backticks to have the same typing behavior as in Sublime Text?

Comment: Your font is not even a monospaced console font… have you tried changing the font? And to be clear, you also want to change the behavior of how VS Code deletes backticks automatically?

Comment: how is the appearance related to VS code when it's the font that decides the shape?